# Javascript - How to get value of specific row or span when class name is used many times

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="toggler">
<div class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <h3 class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all togglerHeader">
        Retail Customer</h3>
    <div class="togglerContent">
        <div class="container container-peloton">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span2 offset2">
                    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The CustomerIsBusiness field is required." disabled="disabled" id="rbRetailCustomerIsBusinessYes" name="Connect.CustomerIsBusiness" type="radio" value="True" />
                    <label for="rbRetailCustomerIsBusinessYes" style="padding-right: 60px">
                        Business</label>
                </div>
                <div class="span2">
                    <input checked="checked" disabled="disabled" id="rbRetailCustomerIsBusinessNo" name="Connect.CustomerIsBusiness" type="radio" value="False" />
                    <label for="rbRetailCustomerIsBusinessNo">
                        Individual</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span6">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="span2 text-right"><label for="Connect_CustomerFirstName">First Name</label></div>
                            <div class="span4">
                                <span class="readonly-field">Rick</span>
```

On the above table, how can I get the value of readonly-fields e.g. "Rick" using Javascript?  I can get the value by using wb.document.getElementsByClassName("readonly-field") however the row value is dynamic and changes. I need a solution that refernces the label in span 2.

Comment: Use ID's https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_syntax.asp

Comment: Is there an event? Do you click something that makes you want to look for it?

Comment: @chevybow ID's should not be the "go to" way of getting DOM references. They are simple enough, but you'll find that they create brittle solutions that don't always scale well. Also, it's best not to use W3 Schools, which is well-known to have incomplete, outdated or flat out incorrect information and instead to use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS)

Comment: Please clarify what you are looking for. First, you say you want the value of `.read-only` fields like "Rick", then you say you want the `label` elements within `div` elements that use `.span2` classes.

Comment: @ScottMarcus What would be your "go to" way of getting an arbitrary span value?

Comment: First I should add that I am webscraping this page.  I am after the value of the read only fields of which there are many on the page but I need there corresponding label text / span2 value.

Comment: @chevybow `document.querySelector()`

Comment: @JoeGlass As I asked earlier, please clarify. In your example above, the `.read-only` element doesn't appear to have any "corresponding"  `label` or `.span2` value. What ***exactly*** are you after. Please be very explicit.

Comment: @ScottMarcus The title clearly states "when class name is used many times". If there are multiple matches and queryselector just returns the first match- how does that solve the problem over using unique id's? What if you don't want the first match? OP might not be clear but I'm not sure I understand your approach

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of getting the value using [id's](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_id.asp). Id's should be unique per element

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('sample_id').innerHTML)
```

```html
<div class="toggler">
<div class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <h3 class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all togglerHeader">
        Retail Customer</h3>
    <div class="togglerContent">
        <div class="container container-peloton">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span2 offset2">
                    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The CustomerIsBusiness field is required." disabled="disabled" id="rbRetailCustomerIsBusinessYes" name="Connect.CustomerIsBusiness" type="radio" value="True" />
                    <label for="rbRetailCustomerIsBusinessYes" style="padding-right: 60px">
                        Business</label>
                </div>
                <div class="span2">
                    <input checked="checked" disabled="disabled" id="rbRetailCustomerIsBusinessNo" name="Connect.CustomerIsBusiness" type="radio" value="False" />
                    <label for="rbRetailCustomerIsBusinessNo">
                        Individual</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span6">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="span2 text-right"><label for="Connect_CustomerFirstName">First Name</label></div>
                            <div class="span4">
                                <span class="readonly-field" id="sample_id">Rick</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use **[`element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)** and **[`element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)** to have a truly dynamic way of getting the results you want.

```js
// First, locate the element with the readonly-field class
let ro = document.querySelector(".readonly-field");

// Then, get it's nearest ancestor that has the row class
let row = ro.closest(".row");

// Then, get the first label that is a child of the row
let lbl = row.querySelector("label");

// Finally, do what you want with that label
console.log(lbl.textContent + ": " + ro.textContent);
```

```html
<div class="toggler">
<div class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <h3 class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all togglerHeader">
        Retail Customer</h3>
    <div class="togglerContent">
        <div class="container container-peloton">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span2 offset2">
                    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The CustomerIsBusiness field is required." disabled="disabled" id="rbRetailCustomerIsBusinessYes" name="Connect.CustomerIsBusiness" type="radio" value="True" />
                    <label for="rbRetailCustomerIsBusinessYes" style="padding-right: 60px">
                        Business</label>
                </div>
                <div class="span2">
                    <input checked="checked" disabled="disabled" id="rbRetailCustomerIsBusinessNo" name="Connect.CustomerIsBusiness" type="radio" value="False" />
                    <label for="rbRetailCustomerIsBusinessNo">
                        Individual</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span6">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="span2 text-right"><label for="Connect_CustomerFirstName">First Name</label></div>
                            <div class="span4">
                                <span class="readonly-field">Rick</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```